# Radon remediation in a part-time home

Tags: energy-efficiency, radon

We have a second home that we use approximately 1 week/month year-round, and more in the summer.   When we purchased the home in 2019, it was tested at 9pCi/L, and a remediation system was installed before closing, with subsequent testing at 1.4pCi/L.
I'm wondering if there's a point to running the system full-time, when we are only there part time (and especially now when our normal schedule isn't likely to happen for an extra month or two).  When we are not there, this system is the major energy consumer in the house, at approximately 2.5-3 kWh/day.   I have the ability to programmatically turn the system off and on, and I'm thinking I could either run it part-time (say 6h/day) or not at all, turning it on full-time several days or even a week before our anticipated arrival.   Given that the un-remediated readings were modest, it seems the risk doing this should be low.

- Will having the system on, then off possibly create higher levels than previously existed (for example, because the continuous suction
  has created new pathways for it)?
- Would running the system on a daily cycle be more effective by sweeping whatever is seeping out of the group up more regularly?

Comment: Have you actually put a Kill-a-Watt on the radon system and measured its draw?  Or did you infer that number in a "what else could it be" fashion? Because you could run 3-4 refrigerators on that draw.

Comment: It is most likely that running the system for as little as 8 hours will flush the basement  volume.   A remote-turn-on system is classiest, for sure,  but  even if you don't turn it on until you get there the sum exposure to you is small.  Radon mediation is aimed at keeping it safe for 24/7/365 living, not short vacations.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica It was measured with a Z-Wave power reporting switch module.

Answer (score -2):

Edited; I have only read testing reports and wired abatement pumps. I modified my answer based on the feedback. As I have said in other posts granite especially pink or rose can be a significant source of radon.
I would not run the system while you are away, I probably would open the house lower level windows or vents when you arrive. You may even want to set up a automated system that you can remotely turn on the abatement system the day prior to your arrival.  Exterior vents at the lowest level with make up air for a while would purge the home of this gas and purging and having the system running prior to arrival might work fine but test to verify if the numbers are low this can save $$$!

Comment: Radon is about 7 times HEAVIER than air.  So it SINKS rather than rises.  Your advice is dangerous since opening the upper level windows will do nothing to relieve any radon trapped in the lower part of the house.  Radon abatement systems do NOT remove radon from the home but rather prevent it from getting in by removing it from the area under and around the foundation where it can infiltrate into the living space.  Left undisturbed, radon settles to the LOWEST part of the structure.

Comment: All the testing I have had done has shown up in upper levels, if radon was heavier than air how is it raising up and getting into homes with crawl spaces? The discharge is required to be above the home also I have wired several systems but not the installer of the plumbing. If it is heavier then the lower area vents would be the correct.

Comment: It's easily raised to upper levels because of air currents and such but it will be concentrated in places like basements.  Radon gas has a density of 9.73 kg/m3, which is VERY heavy where "air" has a density of about 1.225 kg/m3.  Anyway read about it here: https://www.epa.gov/indoor-air-quality-iaq/why-must-radon-be-vented-air-above-my-homes-roof-0

Comment: @jhw20 I did have additional testing in the original answer And have modified the answer, I find it strange the high concentrations on the 2 houses were on the middle and upper floors but the radon source on the middle floor house ended up being the granite counter tops.

Comment: A counter top won't put out meaningful amounts of radon. Or rather - if it does, radon is the *least* of your worries. Radon is a problem because your house sits on top of thousand of tons of rock, not because half a ton of it.

Comment: @Vidarlo You are absolutely wrong here. After the counter tops were removed the count went from ~ 5.5 to zero !  I have seen this 2 times I did not know of it previously and have commented on in this forum several years back!

Comment: How was the radon content measured? Or did you just measure general radioactive decay close by the counter tops? Typical uranium content in rocks is <100ppm...

Comment: It just depends on the specific rocks that the countertops were made of.  Some rocks contain significantly more Uranium than others which is what generates Radon.

Comment: The measurements were on each floor by an inspection company the owners hired me to wire the abatement system the first time I was there the beautiful rose granite covered a large counter top and island, I was later called to remove the electrical Tombstones in the island as it was being removed the abatement system was disabled and the test came back at zero. This was my first experience , after that another but the levels were lower and the new owners had the abatement system and left the counter tops. All I know is that testing company tests for radon with large granite and rose has problem

Comment: @EdBeal I'm inclined to guess a false reading from radioactivity in the stone. For it to produce any significant amount of radon, it'd have to be rather active itself. Radon has a halflife of days; the uranium and radium have halflifes in thousands and tens of thousands of years. Thus, for there to be a significant amount of radon, there has to be a very significant amount of uranium or radium.

Comment: I know it is unusual in my area and both the homes that had above the accepted limits had pink or rose granite I did look it up and it is a cause and some quarries are worse than others.

Comment: @EdBeal It's still **really** improbable. Uranium, which has half life in tens of thousands of years decays to radium, which has half life in thousands of years, which decays into radon, which has half life in days. Each radon atom comes from a decay. For there to be a significant amount of short-lived radon, there has to be a **shitload** of long-lived uranium and radium, which will give off it's own radiation. A few hundred kilos will not do that. Look up [decay chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decay_chain#Uranium_series) for more information.

Comment: I provided the facts. This is not a discussion you have the right to down vote I disagree when I found an error in my answer it was corrected.

Comment: The problems is that the facts are probably not what you believe. I choose to point that out, so that errors are not left on the site. If you want me to elaborate my reasoning further, I'm happy to do so in [chat]. Please don't take this as an personal attack; it ain't.